# How to create a relationship with existing object in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have two entities Contacts and Message. Both the entities have two common attributes i.e contactId in Contacts table and senderId in Message table. I already have contacts in contact table. I want to create a relationship between message senderId with existing contact during the insertion of new message in message table. So that next time when i retrieve that message it will revert message with complete sender information.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve object of contact and set the object to senderInfo in Message Managedobject model.

Contact *contactObject;

[messageObject setSenderInfo:contactObject];;